# redirect the link present on Homepage

Tags: django

I am developing a dashboard for an app by using Django. On the dashboard, there are hyperlinks to the days means when I click on a specific day, I will get the data that is present for that user and for that day.

**In the index.html** :

```
href="{% url 'mailpieces:get_day_mailpiece' question_id=user_id day=date  %}">{{ day }}
```

so get_day_mailpiece function takes two arguments and returns the data, but I am getting that data on the redirected page, I want that data of that day on the same page, on the dashboard.

Comment: Have you heard about AJAX technology?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AJAX:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Try it with jQuery if you are novice to Javascript:

```
{% block javascript %}
  <script>
  $("#test").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "{% url 'mailpieces:get_day_mailpiece' question_id=user_id day=date %}",
         success: function(data){
             $('#result').html("<h2>" + data.responseText+ "</h2>")
            }
    });
    return false;
  });
  </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <input type="text" value={{ day }}/>
  <button id="test" type="submit">Click</button>

  <div id="result">Result will be displayed here</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20655868)

Comment: @MatheusLacerda made changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to send the request. Response will be returned as JSON which you need to parse and display relevant information.
Something like below.

```
$.ajax({
    url : $(element).attr("data-url"),
    data : {
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : $(element).siblings("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']" ).val(),
        "user":user_id,
        "day": day
    },
    method: "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function (returned_data) {            
        // display data 
    }
});
```

If request is not post, no need to worry about csrf token.

In case of get request, use below code.

```
$.ajax({
url : $(element).attr("data-url"),    
method: "GET",
dataType : "json",
success : function (returned_data) {            
    // display data 
}});
```

You can trigger this ajax call on click of a button (or link). Define an attribute `data-url` in button or link with value equal to `{% url 'mailpieces:get_day_mailpiece' question_id=user_id day=date  %}`

```
<button data-url={% url here %} onclick=get_data_by_ajax(this); class="btn btn-link">Get data for day 1</button>
```

For detailed step by step process refer [this article](https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/130/how-to-use-ajax-with-django/).

Just in case if you mean to say data is being displayed in new tab, remove the `target=_blank` from your link.